# CSS Rotate and Vertical Align within a TD

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS code:

```
td{width:50px;-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);}
```

This rotates the text to run vertically from bottom to top, which is what I need.

However, what I would like to do is now align the text to the bottom of the TD.

I've tried using `vertical-align:bottom;` but no joy, also tried `text-align:left;` again, no joy.

Any advice welcomed!

http://jsfiddle.net/74cmg/5/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have any <td>

Comment: does it need to be a table?

Comment: could you add a pic of what you are looking for as an end result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing.

Modify your HTML by wrapping the labels in a `div`:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="header">
            <th class="question"><div>Question</div></th>
            <th><div>Current</div></th>
            <th><div>Previous</div></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For the CSS, use the following:

```css
table {
    display: block;
    width:285mm;
    height:199mm;
    font-size:10pt;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:287mm;
    max-height:300mm;
    border-spacing:0px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
th {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
th div {
    transform:rotate(270deg);
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    bottom: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
tr.header {
    height:125px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Instead of rotating the `th`, rotate the `div` within the `th`.  You need to adjust the bottom offset on the `div` to align the label to the bottom edge of the table header cell.
This is not perfect but offers some hope.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/yCVUa/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="header">
        <td>Question</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Next</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Previous</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS:

```
table {
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
border:1px solid #000;
margin:0 auto;/*you can use margins to compensate for the rotation */
width:100px
}

tr {
height:50px;
}
```

In this example, when you rotate the table, the "top" will run off the left side, so margins can push it out.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/cy9Yw/4/

Comment: Why are you rotating the table?

Comment: @leftside - thanks for the reply - I'm not looking to rotate the whole table.